# ContentDialog is always fullscreen when Title is set

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I have FullSizeDesired="False" in xaml but content dialog in Windows Phone store app is always shown fullscreen when Title is set (with static text or via binding), is there a way to prevent it? Thanks.